# Enviar Imagen Scaneada, Web Socket

Tags: c#, html5, base64, websocket

Mi problema esta al utilizar el protocolo `ws` Web Socket que envia una cadena gigante (una cadena de tamaño de unos 7 a 8 digitos **ej:78872125**) que es una imagen que escaneo y la convierto en base 64 y luego la combierto a `bytes` para poder enviarlo a través del protocolo.

Esta es la sección de código en **`c#`** donde `client.Send(Bytes, Bytes.Length, SocketFlags.None);` es la parte donde envio el mensaje hasta una **web socket** en `HTML5`.

```
private static void OnAccept(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        try
        {
            Socket client = null;
            string headerResponse = "";
            if (serverSocket != null && serverSocket.IsBound)
            {
                client = serverSocket.EndAccept(result);
                var i = client.Receive(buffer);
                headerResponse = (System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer)).Substring(0, i);
                Console.WriteLine(headerResponse);

            }
            if (client != null)
            {
                var key = headerResponse.Replace("ey:", "`")
                          .Split('`')[1]                     
                          .Replace("\r", "").Split('\n')[0]  
                          .Trim();

                var test1 = AcceptKey(ref key);

                var newLine = "\r\n";

                var response = "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols" + newLine
                     + "Upgrade: websocket" + newLine
                     + "Connection: Upgrade" + newLine
                     + "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: " + test1 + newLine + newLine;
                client.Send(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response));

                var i = client.Receive(buffer);
                //Console.WriteLine("Iniciando escanneo");
                string msasd = "";
                try
                {
                    List<string> devices = WIAScanner.GetDevices();
                    ICommonDialog instance = (ICommonDialog)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(new Guid("850D1D11-70F3-4BE5-9A11-77AA6B2BB201")));

                    Device device = instance.ShowSelectDevice(WiaDeviceType.UnspecifiedDeviceType, true, false);
                    if (device != null)
                    {
                        List<Image> images = WIAScanner.Scan(device.DeviceID);
                        foreach (Image image in images)
                        {
                            Bitmap objBitmap = new Bitmap(image, new Size(1250, 1550));
                            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                            objBitmap.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                            msasd = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    //
                }
                //Console.WriteLine("Escaneo Terminado...");
                //Console.WriteLine("Iniciando Envio de paquete");
                byte[] Bytes = CodificarMensajeParaEnviar(msasd);
                client.Send(Bytes, Bytes.Length, SocketFlags.None);

                //Console.WriteLine("Envio Terminado");
                //Console.WriteLine("Se enviaron {0} bytes de informacion", msasd.Length);
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException exception)
        {
            throw exception;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (serverSocket != null && serverSocket.IsBound)
            {
                serverSocket.BeginAccept(null, 0, OnAccept, null);
            }
        }
    }
```

Bueno Ahora el `script` de mi **html** donde recibo el mensaje que es la imagen escaneada en base64 que envia **C#**, donde

```
ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
                cadena=evt.data;//aqui deberia de llegar mi mensaje
                cFunction(cadena);
            };
```

**evt.data** es la cadena que contiene el resultado y pues bueno posterior a eso lo envio a almacenarse por ajax a una ruta de **Laravel** donde no existe problema alguno, el **script** completo es:.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function scannear(){
        loadDoc("ws://127.0.0.1:9000", myFunction);
    }
    function loadDoc(url, cFunction) {
        var cadena="";
        if ("WebSocket" in window) {
            var ws = new WebSocket(url);
            ws.onopen = function () {
                alert("Esta a punto de escanear documentos, asegurese de que la impresora este encendida");
                ws.send("scannear");
            };
            ws.onerror = function (error) {
                console.log('WebSocket Error');
            };
            ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
                cadena=evt.data;//aqui deberia de llegar mi mensaje
                cFunction(cadena);
            };
            ws.onclose = function () {
                $("#mymodal").modal();
            };
        }else{
            $("#mymodalchrome").modal();
        }
    };
    function myFunction(cadena) {
        $.ajax({
            url:'{{url('submitimagen')}}',
            type:'post',
            data:{imagen:cadena,_token:'{{csrf_token()}}',type:"documento"},
            success:function(data){
                if(data.ok){
                    setTimeout('location.reload()',1000);
                }else{
                    alert("error");
                }
            },
            error:function(error){
                console.log("error:"+error);
                alert(error);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Bueno espero se haya entendido con ese pedacito de codigo ya que publicar todo seria muy largo y aburrido leerlo para ustedes.

> **Entonces el problema solo es enviar/recibir ese dato gigante**
>    **Ya que con cadenas cortas como `"hola mundo"` funciona todo correctamente**

Comment: Que implementacion de websocket estas usando en c#? en la implementacion nativa de microsoft hay una forma de enviar el paquete particionado por defecto pero implica hacer el codigo para la concatenacion del byte[]

Comment: Pues `using System.Net.Sockets;` es la libreria y `static Socket serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
        SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);` instancio el objeto.

Comment: Puedes enviar la imagen por "tramos" y poner un carácter especial para indicar el final de la imagen. En el servidor sólo deberías ir concatenando lo recibido hasta el carácter especial. Una vez concatenado ya puedes volver a crear la imagen.

Comment: hola @Trauma, podrías poner un ejemplo de como hacer lo que indicas.

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano gracias por el consejo tratare de implementarlo

Comment: Dices que la conviertes a base 64 y luego a bytes, yo creo que ahí esta el problema. Cuando pasas a bytes aparecen caracteres extraños que suelen tirar las conexiones. Deberías enviarlo en base64 sin pasarlo a bytes o en su defecto primero a bytes y luego a base64. Pero si al final son bytes corres el riesgo que los caracteres raros o la codificación te tiren la conexión.

Comment: @abrahamhs solo encuentro la función `client.Send(Bytes, Bytes.Length, SocketFlags.None);` y otras funciones `Send` que solo envia bytes y no asi `base64` ahi el problema, y en **caso de no convertir primero a `base64` y solo enviar directo `bytes `  ¿como convierto  los bytes a imagen en mi script???**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102005/how-to-convert-byte-array-to-image-file

Comment: @abrahamhs si ves mi código es lo que hago, ahora el problema es enviar y recibir.

Comment: @Shassain Como te fue con tu pregunta? lograste respuesta ...?

Comment: Buenas tardes estoy tratando de comunicarme con el usuario shassain para ver si me da unas orientaciones en websocket ya que tengo que realizar impresión remota desde websocket. Aunque encontre un chat de ejemplo en internet me funciona remotamente pero no se como adaptarlo para que me imprima remotamente a través de websocket tampoco puedo enviar mensajes porque soy nuevo y la plataforma no me deja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saludos, solucione el problema con todos los consejos que me brindaron, para lo cual ahora publico la solución:

**Reemplace el siguiente código**

```
//Console.WriteLine("Escaneo Terminado...");
//Console.WriteLine("Iniciando Envio de paquete");
byte[] Bytes = CodificarMensajeParaEnviar(msasd);
client.Send(Bytes, Bytes.Length, SocketFlags.None);
//Console.WriteLine("Envio Terminado");
//Console.WriteLine("Se enviaron {0} bytes de informacion", msasd.Length);
```

Por un algoritmo de partición de `Bytes` y enviarlo por tramos(como aconsejaron), el codigo es el siguiente:

```
//Console.WriteLine("Escaneo Terminado...");
//Console.WriteLine("Escaneo Terminado...");
//Console.WriteLine("Iniciando Envio de paquete");
int particion = msasd.Length / 100;
int mod = msasd.Length % 100;
for (int l = 0; l < 100; l++)
{
    byte[] Bytes = CodificarMensajeParaEnviar(msasd.Substring(particion*l,particion));
    int k = client.Send(Bytes, Bytes.Length, SocketFlags.None);                    
}
if (mod != 0)
{
    byte[] Bytes2 = CodificarMensajeParaEnviar(msasd.Substring(particion * 100));
    int k2 = client.Send(Bytes2, Bytes2.Length, SocketFlags.None);
}
else {
    byte[] Bytes2 = CodificarMensajeParaEnviar("");
    int k2 = client.Send(Bytes2, Bytes2.Length, SocketFlags.None);
}
//Console.WriteLine("Envio Terminado");
//Console.WriteLine("Se enviaron {0} bytes de informacion", msasd.Length);
```

Dividí el mensaje en 100 partes, pero se envian 101 mensajes en caso de que existan residuos o no(si no existen residuos envió una cadena vacía), para lo cual en lado del cliente recibo 101 mensajes de la siguiente forma:

```
var cant=0;
ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
    cadena+=evt.data;
    cant++;
    if(cant==101){
        cFunction(cadena);
    }
};
```

Concatene los mensajes y todo salio bien, gracias por la ayuda de todos.

Answer (score 2):

La implementacion de websocket como la de cualquier socket requiere que des el suficiente tiempo para hacer que la trama llegue completa, cuando envia un dato pequeño como un hola mundo, funciona porque el dato se puede extraer con solo leer el buffer una vez, pero con una imagen, por el tamaño que suele ser mas de 1024 bytes, no se puede leer completo con una sola lectura, entonces hay varias estrategias para abordar este problema

- la primera es que usted mismo agregue a los primeros 4 bytes el tamaño de la trama para que despues usted trate leer esa cantidad de bytes y asegure la imagen(con un while y haciendo una pausa), ahora esta estrategia seria si fuera un socket puro.
- Otra estrategia es partir el paquete o la imagen en este caso de forma que se envien paquetes pequeños de mismo tamaño, de forma tal que siempre se asegure que voy a leer una cantidad de datos que tengo planeada, lo cual combinada con la anterior estrategia, me garantizan la lectura del paquete
- Para un websocket el ya nos avisa cuando el mensaje llega completo o no, usando la propiedad WebSocketReceiveResult.EndOfMessage de la implementacion propia de .net ahorrando el trabajo de tener que entramar para lograr establecer el tamaño de trama, tambien el suele partir la trama y enviarla por pedazos, lo que implica el uso obligado de la propiedad que hago mencion. en los siguientes links hay un ejemplo de como usar websocket y en los comentarios documentan el uso de la propiedad a la que hago mencion.

https://github.com/paulbatum/WebSocket-Samples/blob/master/HttpListenerWebSocketEcho/Server/Server.cs

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/The-simple-WebSocket-4524921c

Cualquier duda quedo atento